# what would be the best way to creat an infinite vast playback using IMA sdk?

Tags: video, ads, google-dfp, vast, imasdk

While playing a video I would like at specific times to run an infinite playback of VAST ads using IMA js sdk.
Or, just playback vast ads for a specific time frame.
This should happen using the same VAST url with different correlator value.
What would be the recommended approach or solution?

Answer (score 0):

From your summary I am not sure if that exactly meets your request here, but it sounds like VMAP could be the correct approach, http://www.iab.com/guidelines/digital-video-multiple-ad-playlist-vmap-1-0-1/ "XML template that video content owners can use to describe the structure for ad inventory insertion when they don’t control the video player or the content distribution outlet."

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer I've received from goolge-ima-sdk official forum:

*You can call the ad tag again when you see that the ALL_ADS_COMPLETED event is fired instead of calling the CONTENT_RESUME_REQUESTED event. The CONTENT_RESUME_REQUESTED event is fired, when video content has started loading. The video content will start playing at this time after the previous ad and before the next ad response is returned as well as parsed.